# byte[] won't parse to an image

Tags: java, android, image, arrays

I have this custom adapter for my listview that is getting filled with a ArrayList of a custom rowItem class where I put data in.

`rowItem.getImage()` will return this byte array: 
I have put the long string under this in a `byte[]` variable with `getBytes()`

```
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
```

Now I have this code:

```
    byte[] imageData = rowItem.getImage();
    Drawable logoDrawable = null;
    if (imageData != null) {
        Bitmap logoBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageData, 0,
                imageData.length);
        logoDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(context.getResources(), logoBitmap);
    }
    holder.imageView.setImageDrawable(logoDrawable);
```

But it won't display a image, if I set a image out of my drawable map it will show so it reconizes the imageview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you've shown isn't a byte array - it's text, which looks very much like base64 data.

You should try [decoding it from base64](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html#decode%28byte%5B%5D,%20int%29) to "raw" bytes first:

```
byte[] imageData = Base64.decode(rowItem.getImage(), Base64.DEFAULT);
```

... or fix wherever you're getting `rowItem` from to perform the base64 decoding for you.

Answer (score 1):

The data looks like base64 encoded binary data. [`Base64.decode()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Base64.html) it first and then pass the decoded data to `BitmapFactory`.